# How many different ways to combine all lower- and upper-case letters and digits?

Tags: combinatorics

How would one go about calculating how many unique character strings would result from combining any five characters from the set of lower-case letters, upper-case letters, and digits 0 to 9?  For example, 'aaaaa', 'AAAAA', 'zzzzz', 'ZZZZZ', '00000', and '99999' are all acceptable but something random like 'aK9w2' would be the most likely outcome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2\times 26+10$ digits, so the answer is $62^5$. $62$ choices for the first, second, third, ... digits

As an aside, 'aK9w2' is just as likely as  '99999'

Comment: You beat me to it by six seconds. (He's also probably talking about the string format; a random string is is more likely than a familiar string,)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ What is a random or familiar string?

Comment: Colloquial terms; the first is an apparently random (no similar characters), the second is a string that has an identifiable pattern.